# Error on custom middleware checking the value returned on a Model custom Function Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I have an account email confirmation for my Laravel app, then I want to check when the user tries to log in, if the user has activated his account.

I found this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-test-if-a-user-which-tries-to-log-in-is-confirmed-yet

I have a custom model function isActivated that only return the state attibute(boolean type, named estado in spanish) on user model.

On my User Model:

```
public function isActivated()
{
    return $this->estado;
}
```

I created my middleware similar as the link above provided advices, then I registered in App/Http/Kernel.php as a middleware route

The problem comes when I assign my middleware to my route (instead of create the construct function in my controller, I want this middleware just on post request of the login controller).

When I tried to log in throws an error:

```
Fatal Throwable Error: 
Fatal Error: Call to a member function isActivated() on null
```

My middleware looks exacts as the link

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

 class RedirectIfNotMailActivated
{
/**
 * The Guard implementation.
 *
 * @var Guard
 */
protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new filter instance.
 *
 * @param  Guard  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( ! $this->auth->user()->isActivated()) {
        return redirect('/login')
            ->with('mensaje',
                   '¡Lo sentimos, no ha confirmado su cuenta aún!');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
 }
}
```

The fun part: if I add the content of the handle function of my middleware in the App/Http/Middleware/Authenticate(auth middleware) and then I group and attach  some routes to this middleware, this works as expected (not allowing non confirmed users to login)

The problem is that I have a polimorphic relationship in users table for user type (Admin and Customer) so I attached and grouped the admins control panel to auth middleware because I need to restict the access to control panel just for authenticated users and admin type(not allowed for customer user type).

Restriction only takes part on Admin User type.

And of coursethis let the Customer user types can login because I have nothing that restict the if his account is confirmed or not.

What am I doing wrong... The isActivated model function work ok when added in auth middleware, but no when I use this same approach in my custom middleware.

Thanks....

**EDITED**

My middleware asigned to my post method for my login controller

```
Route::post('/login', [
        'middleware' => 'activated.email',
        'uses' => 'loginController@store'
]);
```

PD: sorry for long post and bad english habilities, it is not my first language :(

Comment: Can you paste how you assign this middleware to your route?

Comment: Of course, I have edited my post adding the route definition :) @TheFallen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with our logic. Your **login** path should not be protected with am activated user, because middleware is executed before the request, so the user can't event attempt to login in your case and you get an error because of that.

What you can do instead is add your `isActivated()` check in the **Authenticate** middleware, so there you'll have a logged user and `$this->auth->user()` won't be null.

Comment: But to be honest,  I dont want to add my is Activated check to the auth middleware, because I use this middleware and other middleware that  I created to restict acces to the admin's control panel route access. So if the user that tries to login is not admin type use, he success on login because nothing check on his auth attemp that his account is not confirmed yet.

Comment: Other aprroach I get is in my post method on login controller when I check Auth::attemp I then checked if  ! Auth::user()->isActivated an if its return false I log him out inmediately and redirect lo login form. I know this sound bad practice, an I prefer to implement a middleare just for this, but the middleare approac is failing...

Comment: @elotgamu yes, in the controller would be best, you'll then be able to return to the login form and say that the user must activate the account before login.

Comment: So, You thinks it is good to place this check on my login controller?

Comment: @elotgamu yes, it's the best place, after `Auth::attemp()` confirms the user credentials are valid, you check if the account is activated and return to the login page if it's not.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your usefull comments, you answer help me to get the best approach.